# Am observing issues printing in python when using os.listdir

Tags: python-3.x, winforms

I
am not able to understand why all below prints work when I comment the first one. But when I uncomment the first `print(os.listdir....)`, I get an error from the interpreter: why is this so?

```
import os
print(os.listdir(r"\\ftlengnas.eng.test.net\CWCDevops$\Dms\Staging\APS\Roles\\")
print('c:\waste')
print(r'c:\waste')
print(r'c:\waste\\')
print("c:\waste\\")
```

OutPut:

```
    print('c:\waste')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't get any error when i comment the first `print(os.listdir.....)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the last `)` in that print statement.

```
print(os.listdir(r"\\ftlengnas.eng.test.net\CWCDevops$\Dms\Staging\APS\Roles\\")
```